# Get Value of Property inside a Lambda Expression using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

I have an object called SearchDetails which contains:

```
SearchDetails: 
{ ColName: "StrName"
  SearchVal" "mega" }
```

I am making a generic lambda expression by using reflection method.

```
    public dynamic searchMethod(object SearchDetails)
    {
        ParameterExpression Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SearchDetails), "x");

        var searchCol = Expression.Property(
         Parameter,
         SearchDetails.GetType().GetProperty("ColName")

       );
        var colVal = Expression.Property(
          Parameter,
          SearchDetails.GetType().GetProperty("SearchValue").Name
        );

       Expression contMethod = Expression.Call(searchCol, "Contains", null, colVal);
        Expression<Func<SearchDetails, bool>> lambda =
           Expression.Lambda<Func<SearchDetails, bool>>(contMethod, Parameter);

        return lambda;
    }
```

The problem is that I am getting lambda expressions as follow:

```
{x => x.ColName.Contains(x.SearchValue)}
```

However, I want it to be like this: `{x => x.StrName.Contains("megabrand")}`.
I cannot access the value of the properties: ColName and SearchValue. 
How to solve this problem?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking... We don't know what `StrName` is or where you could get the string `"megabrand"` cames from...

Comment: Then it isn't clear why you can't simply have a `SearchDetails searchDetails` as the parameter of the `searchMethod`

Comment: @xanatos I am having an object at first of my question called SearchDetails which includes the key ColName and its Value: "StrName". (SearchDetails: 
{ ColName: "StrName"
  SearchVal" "mega" })I am using this method because I have to make generic lambda expression where in order to be able to send it many general parameters

Comment: Are you trying to create lamdas of type `Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>>`? Because I can't comprehend what you are trying to do. If `SearchDetails` is the "descriptor" of what search you want to do, what is the object where the search is done? What is the type of `x` in `{x => x.StrName.Contains("megabrand")}`?

Comment: @xanatos I am working with database. In my database I have a table where I should get the search result from it. The result I want to get is: Expression<Func<TbStore, bool>> lambda =
               Expression.Lambda<Func<TbStore, bool>>(contMethod, Parameter); where TbStore is the database table that I am working with. The searchDetail is the object that contains the input text that the user inputs and the column name that the user want his search results

Comment: Ok... Now it is more clear.

Comment: @xanatos Do you have any idea about how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably something similar to this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> SearchMethod<TSource>(SearchDetails searchDetails)
{
    ParameterExpression par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");

    var col = Expression.Property(par, searchDetails.ColName);

    Expression body = Expression.Call(col, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(searchDetails.SearchVal));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, par);
    return lambda;
}
```

Note that you have to pass the type of your table somewhere, in this case as a generic parameter `TSource`.

Use it like:

```
var search = new SearchDetails
{
    ColName = "Foo",
    SearchVal = "Bar",
};

var lambda = SearchMethod<TbStore>(search);
```

As an alternative you could use [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) to obtain something similar.

```
var result = db.Where(searchDetails.ColName + ".Contains(@0)", searchDetails.SearchVal);
```